# How to Pass Empty Values to Array?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I have Data. It has empty value and the values are string.In that some of the strings are empty.It does not have value.Now I want to pass empty string values to Array.Application is crashing if I pass empty values(null and empty) to Array.How to check and send value to Array.Can anyone help me please?

Comment: You can't insert a nil or Null Object to an array.

Comment: I think NSNull can be added to an array.

Comment: Are there any scenarios where one would need to insert null into an array? I'd rather have a clean array, and **maybe** in *very specific situations*, an array holding indexes of the elements that were null in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

STEP 1: check string is empty or not

```
- (NSString *)checkEmpty:(NSString *)check
{
  @try 
  {
    if (check.length==0)
     check = @" ";

    if([check isEqual:[NSNull null]])
     check = @" ";
  }

  @catch (NSException *exception) 
  {
      check = @" ";
  }
}
```

STEP 2:Adding the String to Array

```
  [array addObject:[self checkEmpty:strValue]];
```

If the string value is empty,it takes as above coding after that it passes or adds to array.If the string has value it directly adds to the array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
array_filter();
```

Which manage empty array.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your problem correctly then you are trying to insert a nil value to an array

You cannot insert a nil or a Null value to an array an empty string would be @"".

If this is not what you are looking for please be more elaborate and attach the piece of code along with your question as your question is not clear